# How to access react-native-config ENV variables in babel.config.js?

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) for setting environment variables in my react-native app. Now I want to use the `ENV` environment variable in the `babel.config.js` file to apply a plugin only when running the app in production. Basically what I want to do is apply a babel plugin only when running in production. Is this the correct way to achieve my goal?

How can I use the variable in the babel.config.js file? I tried importing `Config` from the `react-native-config` package and tried to access the variable via Config.ENV but that doesn't seem to work.